# Getting Event Date Facebook Graph Api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently using the **Facebook Graph API** to get some results.
I got almost everything but stucked in event date.

Url-

> https://graph.facebook.com/$page_id/posts?access_token=$access_token&fields=object_id,story,message,full_picture,from,link,updated_time,source,type,caption,description

I need to get the event date.
Any help will be helpfull.
Thanks

Comment: You're querying posts there, post's don't have an event date.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/$page_id/events?access_token=$access_token&fields=name,id,timezone,message,start_time,end_time,picture.type(large),description,category,type,attending_count,interested_count,declined_count
```

For Events I am using this here I am unable to get large image.
I have used picture,full_picture but not getting large size image